# How must a Node JS server be configured to function as an endpoint for a Breeze JS application

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, odata, breeze, rivets.js

At this point, I'm convinced that declarative bindings backed by a robust data query service is the secret sauce for writing scalable rich client applications for the web.

Obviously there are many options for declarative data binding (Knockout JS and [Rivets](http://rivetsjs.com/) for Backbone to name just a few). However, when it comes to querying the server, caching data and tracking changes on the client, the only modular solution that looks half way mature seems to be [Breeze JS](http://breezejs.com/). And yet, while it claims not to dictate server technology, all documentation examples show Breeze running with .NET.

What requirements, API-related or otherwise, must a server fulfill in order to serve as an endpoint for a Breeze application? Is implementing the OData protocol enough? Are there any examples out there to light the way? Or other libraries solving this problem that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nodejs as an oData server with JayData
http://jaydata.org/blog/install-your-own-odata-server-with-nodejs-and-mongodb
it's free and open source

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OData is sufficient. However, we are still working on OData save support (querying is fine, of course).

Sorry for the delay in getting out non-.NET samples. We are definitely committed to an open, pluggable back-end and will be releasing more samples in the next few weeks.

Also, please vote for these features (or submit your own) on our [UserVoice feedback page](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/filters/top). This helps us prioritize what to work on next. Thanks!